# Symfony2 Mapping Model to Entity

Tags: symfony, model, entity

I am currently trying to sort out my user registration in Smyfony2, loosely following their documentation here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html
Sadly, their example is a bit simplistic.

My User Entity has a number of fields which only get added to during registration, and can't be changed there after, so I separated those out from my UserType into my RegistrationType.

The problem now, is that Symfony can't find any of the fields, requested for the form, which live within the User Entity, because it is looking for them in the Registration model. How do I get the Registration model to point to User Entity?
In the documenation example, they avoid all this as the "terms and conditions" checkbox doesn't get added to the database.

e.g. they use this:

```
$builder->add('user', new UserType());
```

but as I mentioned, that only has the fields I want the user to edit after registration.

I tried the data_class, but it complained about Form\Model\Registration wasn't of type Entity\User.

These seems like a really common issue when you are trying to embed bits of forms for a single entity, yet it doesn't cover it in the documentation.

And no, I don't want to use FoSUserBundle.

Comment: You should _look_ at FOSUserBundle's source. It does exactly what you want to do. You should easily be able to mimic it

Comment: It is sad that they don't touch on it in the documentation, as it is about the first things you want to do if you are using types. e.g. a field that you don't want adding to the database is far less common.

Comment: Not sure FoSUserbundle is going to help me very much, as it is basically going from over simplistic documentation to overly complex example.

Comment: its a very abstract example but, i would suggest to start there :]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's possible and really easy to have several form types for the same model class. You can have the `RegistrationType` with lots of fields and then the `UserType` with only some of those fields. Both use the same `User` model.

Comment: I was foolishly expecting not to have to recreate my getters and setters in various different places.

Comment: What you mean by that? You have all the getters and setters in the `User` entity. In form types you just create form fields for the `User` fields.

Comment: Within RegistrationType, I have: $builder->add('displayName', 'text'); and it then tries to look within Registration Model for getDisplayName, rather than the User Entity.

Comment: Are you passing a `User` entity to the form when creating it?

Comment: I inject UserType into RegistrationType and RegistrationType into RegistrationController. Entity\User is specified as the data_class within the setDefaultOptions of UserType.

Comment: You should really show us the code of both types and the action of the controller. Please update your question.

Comment: It is basically the same as: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html except that I am using injection and within the RegistrationType I am adding fields which are in the User Entity. (Which is the one thing their example really ought to do, but doesn't.) As an example, User containers a field for AGE. UserType does not contain AGE as you can't change it after the fact. RegistrationType does have AGE, as that is the only place you can set it. Problem is, RegistrationType looks for setAge in it's model rather than in Entity\User.

Comment: As I said, the code is in the URL I linked. All the code is there. The only difference is getting the field within the RegistrationType to come from the User entity. And if I was the smartest person in the world, I wouldn't be asking the question.